# Threading and information passing -- how to

Tags: python, python-multithreading

To reframe from confusion i have edited the question:

one.py

```
import threading
count = 5
dev = threading.Thread(name='dev', target=dev,args=(workQueue,count,))
dev.setDaemon(True)
dev.start()
workQueue = Queue.Queue(10)
queueLock.acquire()
workQueue.put(word)
queueLock.release()
count = 3
time.sleep(2)
count = 5
```

but my confusion here is I am able to put and get values from queue between threads but in case of count it does not reflect.

Why is that?
What is point am actually missing here?

```
class dev ( threading.Thread ):
    def test(self):
        while 1:
            print count
            print self.EPP_Obj
            queueLock.acquire()
            if not self.workQueue.empty():
                data = self.workQueue.get()
                print data
                queueLock.release()
            else:
                queueLock.release()

    def __init__(self, workQueue, EPP_Obj):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.workQueue = workQueue
        self.EPP_Obj = EPP_Obj
```

Comment: @all : i have modified some part of code..so please ignore errors

Comment: Where exactly are you having problem? Why the dev class is not a `Thread` subclass? What [threading tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+threading+tutorial) are you following? They usually cover what you're asking for.

Comment: @ Rik Poggi : just like below code by arnold is my need but i dont want to use QUEUE mechanism to achieve.just wanna achieve data/Object passing through thread lock.notify mechanism

Comment: @.Ragav: **We're not here to work for you**, read some tutorial, try to solve the problem by yourself and then, if you still have problems, come back with your attempt.

Comment: @RikPoggi : Sorry...ill tell you where i am exactly stuck...EPP_Obj = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]  EPP_thread = threading.Thread(name='t1', target=t1, args=(EPP_Obj,))...it works for the first time but when i do change the object EPP_Obj after starting the thread..like...EPP_thread.start()...time.sleep(2)...EPP_Obj = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]..it doest not reflect in my EPP_thread ... ___init___..but in case if it is a queue object it works...this is the point i am stuck

Comment: @.Ragav: Update your question *(click on the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9190169/edit) button)*, you should post the minimum amount of code that **reproduce** your error and let others **understand** what you're doing. Otherwise is really hard to follow your question (or your comment). A good question will lead to good answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with an example:

The `Thread` subclass:

```
import threading

class Dev(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, workQueue, queueLock, count):
        super(Dev, self).__init__()   # super() will call Thread.__init__ for you
        self.workQueue = workQueue
        self.queueLock= queueLock
        self.count = count

    def run(self):  # put inside run your loop
        data = ''
        while 1:
            with self.queueLock:
                if not self.workQueue.empty():
                    data = self.workQueue.get()
                    print data
                    print self.count

            if data == 'quit':
                break
```

The `with` statement is a smart way to acquire and release a lock, take a look at the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement).

Now the running code:

```
import Queue
import time

work_q = Queue.Queue()     # first create your "work object"
q_lock = threading.Lock()
count = 1

dev = Dev(work_q, q_lock, count)  # after instantiate like this your Thread
dev.setDaemon(True)
dev.start()

time.sleep(1)
with q_lock:
    work_q.put('word')
# word
# 1

time.sleep(1)
count = 10
with q_lock:
    work_q.put('dog')
# dog
# 1

count = 'foo'
with q_lock:
    work_q.put('quit')
# quit
# 1

dev.join()   # This will prevent the main to exit
             # while the dev thread is still running
```

With the code above we have a clear example on how `self.count` stays unchanged no matter what we do to `count`.
The reason of this behaviour is that calling:

```
dev = Dev(work_q, q_lock, count)
```

or

```
dev = Dev(work_q, q_lock, 1)
```

is the same thing.

[Arnold Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9190706/1132524) Showed you a way to change `self.count`. Adjusting that to our example:

```
class Dev(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, workQueue, queueLock, count):
        super(Dev, self).__init__()
        self.workQueue = workQueue
        self.queueLock= queueLock
        self.count = count

    def set_count(self, value):
        self.count = value

    def run(self):
        data = ''
        while 1:
            with self.queueLock:
                if not self.workQueue.empty():
                    data = self.workQueue.get()
                    print data
                    print self.count

            if data == 'quit':
                break
```

Calling `set_count` in our running code will change the value of `self.count`:

```
time.sleep(1)
with q_lock:
    work_q.put('word')
# word
# 1

time.sleep(1)
count = dev.count + 9
dev.set_count(count)
with q_lock:
    work_q.put('dog')
# dog
# 10

count = 'foo'
with q_lock:
    work_q.put('quit')
# quit
# 10
dev.join()
```

I hope this will help you clarify some doubts.

Comment: Isn't a Queue  threadsafe by design, and thus locks would be redundant, versus say a list or something non-threadsafe?

Answer (score 4):

I hope this will help you. I think you don't know which way you need to use.
there are some ways for multi-threading in python.
i introduce the way which use class.
you run below codes. you would understand.

main.py

```
import stringRepeater
import Queue

workqueue = Queue.Queue()
workqueue.put('test1')
workqueue.put('test2')
workqueue.put('test3')

th = stringRepeater.stringRepeater(workqueue,5)
th.start()
print '----daemon is on ----'
th.setCount(3)
workqueue.put('test4')
workqueue.put('test5')
```

stringRepeater.py

```
import threading

class stringRepeater(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, workQueue, count):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.workQueue = workQueue
        self.repeatCount = count

    def run(self):
        while True:
            teststring = self.workQueue.get()
            for i in range(self.repeatCount):
                print teststring

    def setCount(self, newcount):
        self.repeatCount = newcount
```

Comment: yes.i need almost the same..But i need it without queue mechanism.is that possible

Comment: @Ragav you see how i pass 'count' object on __init__(self, workQueue, count):

Comment: thankis for the reply..__init__(self, workQueue, count) here the count value works on the first time of my thread start but when i try it to change the count value after invoking the htread it does not work..but in case of queue am able to operate..

Comment: @Ragav i changed my code. please check again. I think this might help you